# how to fix a copied/migrated HOME folder to secondary partition

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, permissions, mount

I was migrating my hOME folder to secondary partition but I copied with **cp** command intead of using the **rsync** from the [instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving)

I did **cp -var** but still, the files are owned by root and **chown** doesn't work or throw errors.

Seeing that my partition was mounted I went ahead and deleted the original file in the root home directory.

FSTAB

UUID=**************** /home     ntfs    defaults 0 2

Comment: What errors does chown throw?  Also, your home directory on NTFS **will not work properly** because NTFS does not support UNIX style permissions which many files in your home directories **require** to function properly.  By moving to an NTFS partition for your home directory, you've technically botched up your system permissions in a way the system can't recover from easily... it'll be a lot of work to get it to work properly again, probably from a Live environment to get the superuser perms we'd need.

Comment: Thanks for the input :) @ThomasWard

Comment: If someone points you in the right direction, please ask them first if they want to post an answer before you post one yourself.  That behaviour is *frowned upon*  here...

Comment: @ThomasWard good tip on the file permission problem so I changed the FSTAB settings for the partition. **UUID=***************************** /home     ntfs    defaults,uid=1000,gid=1000 0 2**